# How to fix it in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a Dbf table and I need to insert the year and date in the column, the program does not produce any errors but the column is empty

I tried to use query sql queries but failed

```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var year:string;
   pogr_d:string;
   begin
   pogr_d:='';
   year:='';
   year:=copy(formatdatetime('yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date)),1,4);
   Label1.Caption:=year;
   Label2.Caption:=pogr_d;
   if opendialog1.Execute then
   if opendialog1.Filename <> null then
   begin

        TextReader1.FileName := opendialog1.FileName;
        try
              ImportFromText.Execute;
              FDQuery1.Close;
              FDQuery1.Active;
              FDQuery1.SQL.Text:='update g_rabn.dbf set 
    year='+''''+year+'''' +' where year='+''''+'''';
              FDQuery1.ExecSql;

        Except
                  On E : Exception Do
                  ShowMessage(E.Message);
        end;



  end;




  end;

  end.
```

What should happen:
[image]

What i Have:
[image]

Comment: What data type do the columns "date" and "year" have?

Comment: Have you refreshed the data source object connected to the grid?

Comment: Calling UPDATE on the server does NOT refresh the data in the grid, so you need to do that manually, as @TLama says.  Most simply done by closing and re-opening the dataset feeding the grid, but FireDAC has other methods you can look up in the online help.

Comment: Does `importfromText.execute` change the value of `year`?

Comment: 1. Stop concatenating SQL. Use parameters instead. 2. `FDQuery.Active;` does nothing. You use `FDQuery.Close;` or `FDQuery.Active := False;` to close the query. 3. `ExecSQL` runs INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, but does not refresh the query attached to the DBGrid. You need to close and reopen that query in order for the changes to be seen. 4. Converting the date to a string to extract the year doesn't work well, because it doesn't work with different  date formats. Leave the value as a date, extract the year as a numeric using `DateUtils.YearOf()`, and then use `IntToStr` to put it in a label.

Comment: The datasets in the 2 screenshots you've provided don't match. They have different columns. Are you sure the queries are the same, and pulling the correct fields?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that year contains emptystring? Could it be NULL? You can try this sql:

```
'update g_rabn.dbf set year='+''''+year+'''' +' where coalesce(year,'''')='+''''+''''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as an example. I assumed that [Date] and [Year] fields are of NVARCHAR(4) type. I also assumed that you already set up your database connection FConn.

To reproduce this example you will need a Form1 with DBGrid1, DateTimePicker1, Edit1, ADOQuery1, ADOQuery2, DataSource1 and two buttons: Button1 to insert new record and Button2 to update existing ones.

Link your DBGrid1 to ADOQuery1 via DataSource1.

```
uses
  ADODB, DB, DateUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FConn: TADOConnection;
    FYear: Integer;
    FMonth: Integer;
    FDay: Integer;
    FYearUpd: String;
  ...

const
  SQL1 = 'INSERT [Dbf] ([Date], [Year]) VALUES (''%s%s'', ''%s'')';
  SQL2 = 'UPDATE [Dbf] SET [Year] = ''%s'' WHERE Year = ''%s''';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // FConn connection initialization

  ADOQuery1.Connection := FConn;
  ADOQuery2.Connection := FConn;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Dbf';
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FYear := YearOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);
  FMonth := MonthOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);
  FDay := DayOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);

  // Inserting a new record.
  ADOQuery2.SQL.Text := Format(SQL1, [IntToStr(FDay), IntToStr(FMonth), IntToStr(FYear)]);
  ADOQuery2.ExecSQL;

  // Refreshing the DBGrid.
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FYear := YearOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);
  FYearUpd := Trim(Edit1.Text);

  // Updating existing records.
  ADOQuery2.SQL.Text := Format(SQL2, [FYearUpd, IntToStr(FYear)]);
  ADOQuery2.ExecSQL;

  // Refreshing the DBGrid.
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```